# How does Kafka setup a server while performing tests?

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I wanted to understand how Kafka performs tests when we run the command `./gradlew tests` from the root directory of the source code.

There are many tests that require the cluster's connection to the server: `localhost:9000` and so I assumed there must be an actual Kafka running on that port but when I ran the command, `sudo lsof -n -i :9000`, it was empty - no server on that port.

How would this test be performed then that:

- creates a [cluster](https://github.com/kebab-mai-haddi/kafka/blob/KAFKA-12506/streams/src/test/java/org/apache/kafka/streams/integration/AdjustStreamThreadCountTest.java#L81)
- requires a message to be [published on a topic](https://github.com/kebab-mai-haddi/kafka/blob/KAFKA-12506/streams/src/test/java/org/apache/kafka/streams/integration/AdjustStreamThreadCountTest.java#L134) while streaming?

Comment: Do you mean Kafka's open source code?

Comment: Yes, I mean Kafka source code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use localhost, you should be using `CLUSTER.bootstrapServers()`

You can find the source code for the EmbeddedCluster in the streams-test-utils module

Besides that, you should probably be using [TestTopologyDriver](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/streams/developer-guide/testing.html) rather than a Producer, since there's already a method in that class that configures the Stream properties,  to push data into a stream for testing (although, I see no need for any produced data in that test class because it seems you're never consuming anything)

Comment: You are right in the consumption aspect, other tests will change to consume the produced data.

Comment: There is this test, but it appears to intentionally be setup to terminate the thread. The rest of the tests are testing the stream threads, which might not need any data in the topology https://github.com/kebab-mai-haddi/kafka/blob/KAFKA-12506/streams/src/test/java/org/apache/kafka/streams/integration/AdjustStreamThreadCountTest.java#L429

Comment: Why should I be using TestTopologyDriver and not the producer?

Comment: I feel like I answered that already? Because the StreamConfig properties are already defined, that class is testing Kstreams objects, and that class gives you a pipeInput method that does the same thing